# Modeling Disaggregation

Tags: modeling, disaggregation

I'm going to try to explain my problem as simply as possible, but if there's any clarification needed please let me know.

Essentially, I'm predicting that I'm going to sell 100 units total across 5 categories, each with their own supply limitations. What I'd like to do is take this aggregate prediction and divide it out so I can get a prediction for each category. The issue that I'm running into is taking into account both of the limits that I'm dealing with. I can get models that distribute all 100 units but ignore supply limitations, or I can get ones that stay under the supply limits but do not account for all 100 units. Is there any way model this disaggregation, or is my only option to model each category individually and then roll it up into a total forecast?